# Is the [wetlab] tag necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags

There's a new tag called `wetlab`. There seems to be only one (but rather popular) post tagged with this tag. I don't suppose it could generalise to any other question asked so far in Academia.SE.

Is such a tag necessary?

Answer (score 3):

I think the wetlab tag is useful or might become so in the future if this site gets more attention in the natural sciences circles.

Besides, I don't think it's hurting the site in anyways to keep it.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I do not find that the tag 'wetlab' is necessary. A main point of a tag is to be able to search through questions more easily. I'm not sure that a future searcher would necessarily link that question with 'wetlab' which could more easily be applied to chemistry (for example).

Comment: True. Even if the tag is not present, the search result for this word would still pop up the concerned post anyway.

Comment: If there are significant number of questions on a given distinct topic, they need a *specific* tag. It does make search more *precise*.